# LC filter design for 100 kHz PWM to motor

Tags: pwm, motordriver, lc-filter

My system has a Maxon (DCX16L GB KL 24 V) DC motor, which I operate in both directions using 100 kHz PWM (36 V). When I explored it using a spectrum analyzer (zoomed in) and found the peaks of 100 kHz causing this emission going out of range.

I thought this could be due to the sharper rise time of the PWM to motor (~20nS). When I probed the motor cable, I saw 100 kHz ringing (current and voltage), but the ringing frequency is not matching 30 MHz – 70MHz.

I decided to have a LC filter at the (DRV8412) driver output. Here is the filter design:
C = 5 nF
L = 2.7 μH

Cut off frequency of the LC filter:
fc =  1 / (2·Π·√LC) = 1.37 MHz
@ 1.37 MHz, the LC filter will have -3dB of attenuation.

Assuming motor cable inductance is 300 nH, cable capacitance is 80pF. Added 10 Ω in parallel to the inductor as a damping resistor. Since I drive the motor in both directions, I added an LC filter in both directions.

Found resonance @ 23Mhz. (Attached)

Adding snubber near motor, avoids this resonance.

But adding snubber at brd side has the resonance still.

Questions:

1. Though the measured ringing frequency is not 30MHz-70MHz in 100kHz pulse to motor, it is possible to get the radiation due to other resonance?
2. Since the motor is far from PCBA (~4 – 12 inches in different places), it’s difficult to solder the snubber near the motor terminal. Do we need to worry about the resonance? Or can we neglect it?
3. Adding the LC filter smoothens the voltage and current to the motor. Will it also smoothen input power supply to the motor driver IC?

Details are in attached link: [Waveforms and simulation observations](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1z0xKpwMJCXyZ5TkMvxiEIag5hd48to-9?usp=sharing)

Comment: Tip: 'K' for 'kelvin', 'k' for 'kilo', 'Hz' for 'hertz'. Capitals matter!

Comment: Have you tried PWM at something like 1000 Hz, or maybe less? An 80 mm, 1600 rpm, 5 V DC fan can be successfully PWM-controlled at 30–90-ish Hz, and [your motor](https://docs.rs-online.com/6849/0900766b81561b79.pdf) has a maximum recommended speed of 14 000 rpm.

Comment: @AndrewMorton That would probably help, but audible noise might be an issue.

Comment: @JohnD There's an easy way for the OP to find out, and it could save a lot of hassle trying to get rid of RF emissions.

Comment: Ferrite beads have lower resonance peaks, they often helped me in this context.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, but making the PWM to 1kHz likely not possible, since we have to do whole qualification again.. I am thinking LC filter will avoid the fast switching..Is there a way to avoid the resonance as I explained..?

Comment: @NICEGUYNICEGUY Do you have any sort of pre-qualification testing, such that you could investigate if changing to a much lower PWM frequency would save enough money in filter components to pay for the whole qualification again? If you want to make the switching edges less steep, then would adding a bit of resistance to the gate leads of the MOSFETs help?